# How to find all titles including a certain word in SPARQL

Tags: select, sparql

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX leg: <http://www.legislation.gov.uk/def/legislation/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?x leg:title ?y.
  FILTER(?y in ("Education Act 2002"))
}
```

With this query I can match on `Education Act 2002` exactly, but I want to be able to match on it even if I just have the word "Education".

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: that needs a fulltext index support in your triple store if you want to match substrings or even fuzzy strings. So, it depends on the triple store you're using

Answer (score 1):

The [`IN`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in) operator is used for searching in a list of values.

For string pattern matching you can use the [`REGEX`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex) function:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX leg: <http://www.legislation.gov.uk/def/legislation/>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?x leg:title ?y.
  FILTER(regex(?y,"Education")) # this matches any string containing the word "Education"
}
```

Comment: You could also use [`CONTAINS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) instead of `regex`.

Comment: You're right! In the case of plain substrings using the `REGEX` function can be an overkill.